# No branch point on composite function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to know why $f(z)=\sqrt z$  and $g(z)=\sin(\sqrt z)$ have a branch point at $z=0$ but $h(z)=\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{\sin(\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$ has NO brach point at $z=0$

Comment: I changed your title. It's not urgent for anyone else.

Comment: Generally, the word "urgent" implies that you either are in the middle of a test, or started your homework too late.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the Taylor series for $\sin$ and put in $\sqrt{z}$ then divide by $\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: Why $\sqrt z$ has a branch point in $z=0$?